# Grub updated and now I can't get in to the BIOS, how can I fix it?

Tags: boot, grub, bios

Mint 20.2 system. Need to get to the BIOS so that I can boot from the USB stick into GParted, which is suddenly not happening automatically. I upgraded all my packages an hour ago (pretty sure grub updated too). Tried rebooting about five times now, holding down delete or f11 or f3. Delete definitely worked before the upgrade. I have tried pressing it several times and holding it down. I've tried pressing it constantly immediately after starting the reboot process. No matter what I do it just goes to the Mint splash screen.

The chipset is a Intel Celeron 3205U (Broadwell, embedded) if that helps. I can't find any info in the system manual as to the BIOS. I flashed the BIOS about 6 months ago to the most current version. The system is not dual boot. [The machine's product page is here](https://www.newegg.com/msi-cubi-003bus/p/N82E16856167088?Item=N82E16856167088). The MSI product page is less helpful. The system is 6 years old.

Tried `system-ctl reboot --firmware-setup` and it says my firmware does not support that.

Tried `reboot -f` and it didn't go to the BIOS.

Tried a full power down and reboot, still can't get to the BIOS.

Tried editing grub to use `menu` instead of hidden, the grub menu won't show. The timeout is set to 10.

I have gotten in to the BIOS about 10 times in the past 2 days with no issue, just hold down DEL and it get's there. I am positive the USB stick is bootable, I booted in to Clonezilla off of it this morning. It's definitely plugged in.

I know there are similar questions here and I have tried those answers. The only thing I can think to do is factory reset my BIOS but I don't know if that's the smart choice.

Grub config:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Comment: Did you drain all power when you did a full shutdown. If laptop remove battery & hold power switch for at least 10 sec, with mains disconnected. If you totally reset UEFI/BIOS, it will reset everything to defaults, so you have to redo settings. In UEFI/BIOS make sure fast boot is off. And if dual booting with Windows make sure fast start up is off.

Comment: "BIOS make sure fast boot is off" this is impossible for me to do if I can't get to the BIOS. I just unplugged the power (it's a bookshelf system) and will wait 10 minutes before rebooting, then will try holding down DEL key when booting. I doubt it will work.

Comment: Powering down and holding DEL during boot did not work. Same for F3 (pretty sure DEL is the right key but F3 is worth a try). I get a black screen then a few seconds later I see the Mint splash screen. I could reset the BIOS, but do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Try F2, F12, F9.

Comment: I reset the BIOS. It's DEL. But now I have a new problem for a different post...

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/704433/reset-my-bios-now-how-do-i-fix-invalid-signature-detected-check-secure-boot-p 

I got it working. Grub still doesn't show during boot but at least my BIOS recognizes keypresses from the keyboard now. no idea how grub messed that up -- it acted like the grub upgrade changed my bios fast boot settings